# Firebase preventing two different connections updating same record

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, atomic

If I have an event app that reads the db and finds an open event slot and presents a dialog to the user do book it, how do I prevent a second user also opening up the same object and booking it as well?  I can't find mention of a semaphore lock on the db for a record that would prohibit the second connection from making an update to the same record (in rejecting it because the flag on that record is now set to true).

Comment: Did you look into `transactions`? This is the [iOS documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) from firebase in regards to the latter concept.

Comment: Yep that appears to be it.  For some reason my transactions link was going to a different page.  Thanks.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so Jad above pointed out that the way to do this is with Transactions as they will "lock" the record and not allow outside queries to change values.  We can then in the second clients attempt to update the same record, check to see that the scheduled flag was set and thus reject the update.